# Magento sort collection with multiple attributes

Tags: php, sorting, magento

I want to sort Magento product collection  with multiple attributes at catalog product list page. I am using this code

```
$this->_collection->setOrder('price', 'desc');
$this->_collection->setOrder('price_plus_shipping', 'desc');
```

I also tried this code as well

```
$this->_collection->setOrder(array('price', 'price_plus_shipping'),Varien_Data_Collection::SORT_ORDER_DESC);
```

When i sort these both combine its not giving me accurate results but if i use both separately like when i am using only

> price_plus_shipping

its working fine also as

> price

its also working file 
they are showing me accurate results. But i want to use them combine.
in **Price** i have product prices in **price_plus_shipping** i have alphabets like

> a,b,c etc

Answer (score 3):

I have worked on your approach and get the results.
I have created a text type attribute "`price_plus_shipping`".

```
Visible on Product View Page on Front-end => Yes
Used in Product Listing => Yes
Used for Sorting in Product Listing => Yes
```

Now made below changes on `app\design\frontend\[Package]\[Theme]\template\catalog\product\list.phtml`

```
$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
$_productCollection->clear();
$_productCollection=$_productCollection->addAttributeToSort('price', 'DESC');
$_productCollection=$_productCollection->addAttributeToSort('price_plus_shipping', 'ASC');
$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: @OBAID 
Have you checked this solution?

Answer (score -1):

There seems to be a bug in Magento 1.9 with setOrder and multiple columns.  I was able to get this working like this:

```
$this->_collection->getSelect()->order(array('price desc', 'price_plus_shipping desc'));
```